# how to toggle attr() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple add attribute function:

```
$(".list-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".list-sort").attr('colspan', 6);
});
```

My question is: how can I turn this into a toggle, so `colspan="6"` is removed from the element on the next click?

Comment: Have you tried pure JS? There is this method `.toggleAttribute()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute

Answer (score 189, accepted):

If you're feeling fancy:

```
$('.list-sort').attr('colspan', function(index, attr){
    return attr == 6 ? null : 6;
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBrA8/1/)**</kbd>

<sub>ES6 Syntax (2021):</sub>

```js
$('.list-sort').attr('colspan', (_, attr) => attr == 6 ? null : 6));
```

Comment: Super elegant, can you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: @Gcamara14

 `$('.list-sort')` targets the element in the DOM
`.attr()` is a jQuery function to set the attribute value which takes two arguments `attribute` and `value`.
`'colspan`' is the attribute argument in this case and the value is the anonymous function. `function(index, attr){
    return attr == 6 ? null : 6;
}`
This function uses a ternary operator `?` which is similar to an `if statement`. If the `attr` passed equals `6` return `null` else return `6`

Answer (score 64):

```
$('.list-toggle').click(function() {
    var $listSort = $('.list-sort');
    if ($listSort.attr('colspan')) {
        $listSort.removeAttr('colspan');
    } else {
        $listSort.attr('colspan', 6);
    }
});
```

[Here's a working fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/49u2q/5/)

See the answer by @RienNeVaPlus below for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Use jquery method prop() instead of attr() for better browser compatibility

Comment: cache your node. var $listSort = $('.list-sort')

Comment: what does caching by var $listSort = $('.list-sort') do?

Comment: Makes it so you don't have to do two lookups (the first is `.attr('colspan')` and the second is either `.remoteAttr('colspan')` or `.attr('colspan', 6)`)

Answer (score 43):

For readonly/disabled and other attributes with true/false values

```
$(':submit').attr('disabled', function(_, attr){ return !attr});
```

Comment: for me, the attr was `typeof string`, so i wrote `$(selector).attr('aria-expanded', function(_, attr) { return !(attr == 'true') })`

Comment: This is a nice answer, since it trigger the change of attribute only once. Is using it for a toggle switch with 3 possible values ("", "N" and "Y")

Answer (score 12):

I know this is old and answered but I recently had to implement this and decided to make 2 simple jQuery plugins that might help for those interested

usage:

```
// 1
$('.container').toggleAttr('aria-hidden', "true");
// 2
$('.container').toggleAttrVal('aria-hidden', "true", "false");
```

1 - Toggles the entire attribute regardless if the original value doesn't match the one you provided.

2 - Toggles the value of the attribute between the 2 provided values.

```
 // jquery toggle whole attribute
  $.fn.toggleAttr = function(attr, val) {
    var test = $(this).attr(attr);
    if ( test ) { 
      // if attrib exists with ANY value, still remove it
      $(this).removeAttr(attr);
    } else {
      $(this).attr(attr, val);
    }
    return this;
  };

  // jquery toggle just the attribute value
  $.fn.toggleAttrVal = function(attr, val1, val2) {
    var test = $(this).attr(attr);
    if ( test === val1) {
      $(this).attr(attr, val2);
      return this;
    }
    if ( test === val2) {
      $(this).attr(attr, val1);
      return this;
    }
    // default to val1 if neither
    $(this).attr(attr, val1);
    return this;
  };
```

This is how you would use it in the original example:

```
$(".list-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".list-sort").toggleAttr('colspan', 6);
});
```

Comment: Worked for me! Appreciate

Comment: The `else` in `toggleAttr` should be: `$(this).attr(attr, val || '');` for "valueless" attributes.

Answer (score 5):

This would be a good place to use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work):

```
(function() {
  var toggled = false;
  $(".list-toggle").click(function() {
    toggled = !toggled;
    $(".list-sort").attr("colspan", toggled ? 6 : null);
  });
})();
```

The `toggled` variable will only exist inside of the scope defined, and can be used to store the state of the toggle from one click event to the next.

Comment: What if it gets changed from somewhere else?

Comment: I don't know if I follow. Any click on an element with the class `list-toggle` will trigger the function, which changes the boolean variable `toggled`. The attribute is then either set or unset depending on the state of the variable `toggled`.

Comment: @thirdender your code breaks if something other than a click event modifies the state of the attribute.

Comment: Upvoted because this is a very good example of the meaning of a closure

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".list-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).hasAttr('colspan')
        ? $(this).removeAttr('colspan')
        : $(this).attr('colspan', 6);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".list-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('colspan')
        ? $(this).removeAttr('colspan')
        : $(this).attr('colspan', 6);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is counting that the second parameter is useless when calling removeAttr!** (as it was when this answer was posted) **Do not use this otherwise!**

Can't beat [RienNeVaPlus's clean answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665152/2128271), but it does the job as well, it's basically a more compressed way to do the ternary operation:

```
$('.list-sort')[$('.list-sort').hasAttr('colspan') ? 
    'removeAttr' : 'attr']('colspan', 6);
```

an extra variable can be used in these cases, when you need to use the reference more than once:

```
var $listSort = $('.list-sort'); 
$listSort[$listSort.hasAttr('colspan') ? 'removeAttr' : 'attr']('colspan', 6);
```