# How to use button action to toggle between two states of a textarea using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, toggle

In my HTML table I am adding rows dynamically.

[image]

As can be seen in the above image, one of the columns (in each row) has a button (**OpenPad**) which I am using to increase the height of the textarea like this:

```
$('#'+ constructeIdQuesFld).height(65);
```

The aim of this arrangement is to conserve space. The result is as seen in the following image:

[image]

However, if I want to toggle the button action from the default textarea height to increased height and back to default, it is not happening. I have tried the toggle action using the following:

```
$('#'+ constructeIdQuesFld).toggle().height(65);
```

When the button OpenPad is clicked the 2nd time, the textarea is hidden completely, instead of reverting back to the default state. This is stated succinctly [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp#:%7E:text=The%20toggle()%20method%20toggles,This%20creates%20a%20toggle%20effect.):

> The toggle() method toggles between hide() and show() for the selected
> elements.

[image]

**Under the circumtances, how do I toggle between two states of the textarea (from default size to the intended one and back)?**

Comment: could you share the snippet of this , so others get a head start for solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `textarea` instead of `input[type=text]`. Then the toggle function is about changing the value of the `rows` attribute of the corresponding textarea.

```
$('thebutton').click(function(){
   $('thetextarea').attr('rows',  $('thetextarea').attr('rows')==1?5:1);
})
```

Comment: The field in question is already a `textarea`. And ... the good part is **it's working**. Will it be okay if I ask what is the code doing? Thanks.

Comment: Its just using __ternary operator__ to check and assign the new value of the rows attribute. Check this https://gist.github.com/glpzzz/762afe32e8c245216869e9b1bd0aaac0 for the expanded, explanatory version.

Comment: But check this answer!!! It's event more fancy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665152/12115958

Comment: **Suggestion:** for the sake of usability, I would like to have the toggle size functionality when focusing the textarea instead of clicking in a external button. If unfocus, return to original 1 (rows=1)

Comment: Good suggestion. Thanks. I will certainly try this out. BTW, I had thought of the **button** as a kind of flag to inform the user about the availability of the functionality. To draw user attention. Something akin to SAP functionalities / UI. I want to extend this functionality in other areas also. So, let's see. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: As a user I really prefer don't having the button and the textarea autoincreases the size when requested (I focus it)